# Asana Original Workspace

Tags: api, asana

There is no documentation on this so I figured I'd ask about it here.  I'm trying to find out how I can get the workspace id of the original workspace that the user created upon account creation.

From the workspaces endpoint I get the following in order, in the response

original workspace, Personal Projects

If I create another workspace then it goes after the original and before the Personal Workspace, and other ones follow suit...

original workspace, Alex's Workspace, Personal Projects

original workspace, Alex's Workspace, Z Team, Personal Projects

However, I didn't create a support request to make one of the workspaces other than my original and personal an organization type.

**Is the response ALWAYS in this sort of configured order?  If I add another organization type workspace would it then go in front of the original workspace?**

To recap, I want to be able to ALWAYS get the original workspace of the user so I can post to Asana through their API.

Comment: Just to clarify: what do you mean by "original" workspace? You mean the first one a user created? The first one they joined? What if they leave it and join another? Why do you even want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, we don't have a concept of "original" workspace, but the first result for `/users/me` `data.workspaces` is as close a proxy as you're likely to get.

Comment: By the way, how IS the list ordered?

Comment: The best answer I can give is probably "not in any way you should rely on, really". ;-)